# Converting tabs in leading whitespaces to double spaces in Visual Studio macro

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-macros

I'm trying to modify a VS macro I found on this site; the macro performs a transformation to a document when it is saved. I need the macro to transform the leading whitespaces such that each tab characters are replaced with two spaces but leave all the existing spaces intact. I tried the code below but it is not working the way I would like it to. May I get some help with it?

```
    If vsFindResult.vsFindResultReplaced = _
        DTE.Find.FindReplace(vsFindAction.vsFindActionReplaceAll, _
                         "^{ }*\t", _
                         vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression, _
                         "\1  ", _
                         vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetCurrentDocument, , , _
                         vsFindResultsLocation.vsFindResultsNone) Then
        document.Save()
    End If
```

Comment: If you simply go to tools menu->Options, Text Editor->Tabs, you can just Set tab-size = 2 and select "insert spaces" and then this should achieve the same end result...

Comment: I already have it configured that way. It seems to only insert the two spaces with new tabs, and it leaves existing tabs the way they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Productivity Power Tools" from Microsoft. Between many other tools there is a tool called "Fix Mixed Tabs" which is doing exactly what you're searching for.

[Link to description and download Productivity Power Tools in Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)